# Undo (cmd+z) after close file sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I read in some place some months ago about a sublime plugin that saved all history from a file. This is useful for revert back versions even if i closed the file.

Unfortunately i'dont  remenber where i saw this. Someone know ?

Comment: Is this what you're talking about: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/File%20History

Comment: @BlueFox no....

Comment: Ok. Here's one more link. It saves a file's local history: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Local%20History

Comment: Almost that! Missing only the option to undo with cmd+z

Answer (score 0):

AutoBackups does this.

> AutoBackups is a Sublime Text 2/3 plugin, which automatically save a backup copy every time you save or open (if backup file not exists) a file.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoBackups